# How to add/append new lists to an already existing zip?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am programming a grocery list by using dictionaries and functions (i am a beginner) and all of my codes are not here. I have made a zip av 2 lists (an integer asking about the price and one string asking about the item the user want to add). I am using a while loop that allow the user to add items and their prices to those 2 lists. Now i have asked the user to add another item and its price to those 2 lists in the zip and then i should print the new lists. The **problem** i need help with is that im only able to print first item and its price and when i add new ones then it prints nothing. Another thing i need **help** with is to move the "selection_1' to the function "**def alternativ_1()**" and expect it to return **summ** and **add_item**.

I have also tried making new zip like:

```
flatlist = zip(*data)
flatlist.append(add_item)
```

But its not helping.

I am using "

```
from tabulate import tabulate
```

to print those two lists in a table form.

I have made 2 lists, one for item (new_item) and one for the items price (price_item) and then added them to a zip.

```
new_item= []
price_item= []
data = zip(new_item, price_item)
```

```
# def selection_1():
```

```
While true
if selectio1n == 1:
         add_item = input('name? ')
         summ = int(input('sum: '))
         new_item.append(add_item) #only print the first item
         price_item.append(summ)   #only print the first price

elif selection == 2:
selection_2()
bla bla bla

etc
```

Comment: Why use a zip? Having a list of pairs seems more natural for your purposes. It is easy to append a new pair to such a list.

Answer (score 2):

`zip` isn't supposed to be used like that. `zip` returns a one-off iterator, not designed to be useful beyond the context of a single loop. If you want to loop over the items of two lists (or other iterables) together, you call `zip` and iterate over the iterator it gives you. If you want to iterate again, you call `zip` again.

It looks like you're recording item names and prices in two lists, `new_item` and `price_item`. In that case, when you need to record a new item, append the name to `new_item` and append the price to `price_item`. Don't do anything with a `zip` iterator at this point - you shouldn't even *have* a `zip` iterator at this point.

When you need to iterate over these two lists together, *then* you call `zip`.

(Another approach would be to just keep a list of `(item, price)` tuples, or a list of instances of some class that records price and other item info, but the above is how you'd do things with separate lists and `zip`.)